# Django forms filter greater than doesn't work

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to filter a chained dropdown list, so it only shows hora greater than 0. But I don't know why .filter(cupos__gt=0) in forms.py doesn't work but if I try to print it in the terminal it works

**forms.py**

```
class ReservaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Reserva
        fields = ('actividad', 'dia', 'hora')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['dia'].queryset = Dia.objects.none()

        if 'actividad' in self.data:
            try:
                actividad_id = int(self.data.get('actividad'))
                self.fields['dia'].queryset = Dia.objects.filter(actividad_id=actividad_id).order_by('name')
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                pass # invalid input from the client; ignore and fallback to empty Dia queryset
        elif self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['dia'].queryset = self.instance.actividad.dia_set.order_by('name')
        
        self.fields['hora'].queryset = Hora.objects.none()

        if 'dia' in self.data:
            try:
                dia_id = int(self.data.get('dia'))
                self.fields['hora'].queryset = Hora.objects.filter(dia_id=dia_id,cupos__gt=0).order_by('name')
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                pass # invalid input from the client; ignore and fallback to empty Dia queryset
        elif self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['hora'].queryset = self.instance.dia.hora_set.order_by('name')
```

**views.py**

```
def reserva_add(request):
   form = ReservaForm()
   hora = Hora.objects.filter(cupos__gt=0)
   print(hora)
   context = {
       'form': form,
   }
   return render(request, "agenda/reserva_form.html", context)
```

**Terminal**

```
<QuerySet [<Hora:  09:00:00 52 >]>
```

[image]

8 am shouldn't appear

**SOLUTION**

```
def load_horas(request):
    dia_id = request.GET.get('dia')
    horas = Hora.objects.filter(dia_id=dia_id, cupos__gt=0).order_by('name')
    return render(request, 'agenda/horas_ddl.html', {'horas':horas})
```

source: [Dependent dropdown list with Django](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html)

Comment: Your filter condition is different in views and in the form. Probably, the `dia_id=dia_id` filtering condition making the result empty

Comment: I added filter in views to see if __gt worked. But I don't have that filter in views, I still have that error.

Comment: Could you explain how your data looks in the database? You filter by cupos > 0, do you have any data matching this criteria in your database? If so, when you perform this query, what are the exact results besides "8 am shouldn't appear"?

Comment: I just solved it. There's another function in views that loads all the "hora" objects. So I added the filter to that function. Thank you for your time!